# Urllib and saving multiple urls to different filenames

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I have tried searching the urllib documentation, learnpython subreddit and here. Perhaps I am searching irrelevant keywords.

I am looking to download multiple url images to the same directory, although with different file names. How could I achieve this? Provided is the appropriate excerpt.Thank you for your time!

```
def downloaddata():

    urls = ["url1.gif","url2.gif", "url3.gif","url4.gif"]
    filepaths = ["samepath/1.gif","samepath/2.gif","samepath/3.gif","samepath/4.gif"]

    for url in urls:
        try:
            image = urllib.URLopener()
            image.retrieve(url, filepaths)
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i,url in enumerate(urls):
    try:
        image = urllib.URLopener()
        image.retrieve(url, filepaths[i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

you also need to remove `break` from try block, if you want to download all images, Due to break it comes out of loop after one execution

demo:   enumerate gives index and element

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> for i,x in enumerate(a):
...     print(i,x)
... 
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'd')
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Do you know why using try/except would only download one image? After removing try and except, this worked fine.